# Convert date format on fly in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datetime

i am uploading an excel file which has a date column having this format "dd-mm-yyyy". I am trying to convert it on fly into this format mm/dd/yyyy.

```
string[] dsplit = row[6].ToString().Split('-');
obj.ExpiryDate = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", dsplit[1], dsplit[0], dsplit[2]).ToDate();
```

but it throws error, some hidden error.

Here is the whole code. I have tried a alot and nothing works expectedly

```
protected void SaveEmployeefrom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uploadExcelfile();
    }
    public List<ClsEmployee> uploadExcelfile()
    {
        List<ClsEmployee> list = new List<ClsEmployee>();
        DataTable tb = new DataTable();
        try
        {

            if (employeeregistration.HasFile)
            {

                string name = DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss_ddmmyy");
                name = name + employeeregistration.FileName;

                employeeregistration.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFiles/") + name);

                string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFiles/") + name);
                string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".xls")
                {
                    excelconnection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                    excelconnection.Open();
                }
                else if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".xlsx")
                {
                    excelconnection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                    excelconnection.Open();

                }
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Name],[ID],[Mobile No],[Phone],[Emirates],[Nationality],[ExpiryDate],[Address] FROM [sheet1$]", excelconnection);
                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                oleda.Fill(tb);
                foreach (DataRow row in tb.Rows)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[6].ToString()))
                    {
                        ClsEmployee obj = new ClsEmployee();
                        obj.ID = 0;
                        // obj.Employer_ID=row[0].ToInt32();
                        obj.EmployeeName = row[0].ToString();
                        obj.EmployeeUniqueID = row[1].ToString();
                        obj.MobileNumber = row[2].ToString();
                        obj.PhoneNumber = row[3].ToString();
                        obj.Emirates = row[4].ToString();
                        obj.Nationality = row[5].ToString();
                        //from excel its dd-mm-yyyy
                        string[] dsplit = row[6].ToString().Split('-');
                        obj.ExpiryDate = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", dsplit[1], dsplit[0], dsplit[2]).ToDate();
                       // obj.ExpiryDate = row[6].ToDate(); //mm-dd-yyyy
                        obj.Address = row[7].ToString();
                        list.Add(obj); 
                    }

                }
                excelconnection.Dispose();
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    File.Delete(path);
                }
                int total = tb.Rows.Count;
                if (total>0)
                {
                    GV_Employee.DataSource = null;
                    GV_Employee.DataSource = list;
                    GV_Employee.DataBind();
                    GV_Employee.Visible = true;
                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Uploaded successfull !!!", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Yellow);
                    ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
                }
                else
                {
                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("No Record In Excel Sheet !!!", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);
                    ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
                }
               //txtSerialQuantity.Text = total.ToString();

                ////// trbtnCheckAll.Visible = true;
                ////div_automatic.Visible = true;
                ////lbl_totalSelected.Text = "Total Selected = " + total.ToString();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            x.ToString(); //ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes(x.Message, ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);
            ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes(x.Message, ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);
            ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
        }
        return list;
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClsEmployee obj1 = new ClsEmployee();
        List<ClsEmployee> list = new List<ClsEmployee>();
        try
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow item in GV_Employee.Rows)
            {
                ClsEmployee obj = new ClsEmployee();
                obj.ID = 0;
                obj.Employer_ID = cmbEmployer.SelectedValue.ToInt32();// ((Literal)GV_Employee.Rows[1].FindControl("Ltrl_EmployerID")).Text.ToInt32();
                obj.EmployeeName = ((Literal)item.FindControl("Ltrl_Name")).Text.ToString();
                obj.EmployeeUniqueID = ((Literal)item.FindControl("Ltrl_EmployeeUniqueID")).Text.ToString();
                obj.MobileNumber = ((Literal)item.FindControl("Ltrl_Mobile")).Text.ToString();
                obj.PhoneNumber = ((Literal)item.FindControl("Ltrl_PhoneNo")).Text.ToString();
                obj.Emirates_ID = ((Literal)GV_Employee.Rows[1].FindControl("Ltrl_Emirates")).Text.ToInt32();
                obj.Nationality_ID = ((Literal)GV_Employee.Rows[1].FindControl("Ltrl_Nationality")).Text.ToInt32();
                obj.ExpiryDate = ((Literal)item.FindControl("Ltrl_Expiry")).Text.ToDate();
                obj.Address = ((Literal)item.FindControl("Ltrl_Address")).Text.ToString();
                obj.LFMD = "";
                obj.RFMD = "";
                obj.PinCode = "";
                obj.IsFingerAuth = false;
                obj.IsActive = true;
                list.Add(obj);

            }
            obj1.SaveEmployeefromExcelFile(list);
            ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Save successfull !!!", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Yellow);
            ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
            GV_Employee.DataSource = null;
            GV_Employee.Visible = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes(ex.ToString(), ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);
            ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
        }

    }
```

Comment: And what values do you see when you debug this? Date columns in excel do not store their values in any format, that's just how they show it. Dates are numbers, like so many other things in excel.

Comment: `"some hidden error"`? use `try-catch` to find it, and try to get `InnerException` from `exception` what you get.

Comment: Aamir, if I had to guess I'd say that one or more non-date values is in the date column. Just put an additional try catch block around your `obj.ExpiryDate = ` line and you'll see what's happening

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(row[6].toString());
string date = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `row[6]` is a `DateTime` when you get from excel, you just need;

```
row[6].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Convert a `DateTime` to `string` and splitting it a *generally* bad idea. `mm` specifier is for minutes, `MM` is for months by the way.

Comment: i tried ur code but it throws error

No overload for string takes 2 arguments

Comment: @AamirShah What is the type of `row[6]` exactly? Is it `object`, `string`, or `DateTime`? What `row[6].GetType()` returns?

Comment: datetime , it's datatime obj

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
 String MyString = "12-30-2014"; // get value from text field
        DateTime MyDateTime = new DateTime();
        MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "MM-dd-yyyy",null);
        String MyString_new = MyDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```